# Multiple measures ANOVA

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have some data and would like to do a cross sectional analysis which would normally be a one way ANOVA, however, some of my patients have multiple measurements, roughly 20% only. If I want to utilized this data as well, would it make sense to do a mixed ANOVA? The measurements are not time dependent, just repetitions of the same trial.

Comment: mixed model anova sounds great. To get a better answer, we really needs more details.